# Count Sessions based on hits.page.pageTitle

Tags: session, google-analytics, google-bigquery, page-title

I am querying BigData containing Google Analytics export.
Looking for all sessions that visited a page containing the string 'rafinha' so I use this query

```
SELECT
channelGrouping as Default_Channel_Grouping, 
SUM (totals.visits) as Sessions,
SUM(case when hits.page.pageTitle CONTAINS ('rafinha - Dugout') then 1 else 0 end) as Rafinha_Sessions
FROM

(TABLE_DATE_RANGE([133338516.ga_sessions_], 
                TIMESTAMP('2017-10-01'), 
                TIMESTAMP('2017-10-20')))   
GROUP BY Default_Channel_Grouping
ORDER BY Sessions DESC
```

I am not getting the numbers match between BigQuery and Google Analytics > Acquisitions >  Channels

Comment: `hits` is a repeated field, so you may be overcounting `totals.visits` if there are multiple matching `pageTitle` values. Have you tried using standard SQL instead? It's easier to be explicit with repeated field operations.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```sql
SELECT
  channelGrouping,
  COUNT(1) AS Sessions,
  SUM(isRafinhaSession)
FROM (
  SELECT
    channelGrouping,
    SOME(hits.page.pageTitle CONTAINS ('rafinha - Dugout')) WITHIN RECORD     isRafinhaSession
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([133338516.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-10-01'), TIMESTAMP('2017-10-20')))
  WHERE
    totals.visits=1)
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  Sessions DESC
```

The inner query looks for your condition (SOME aggregates multiple booleans with ORs) on session level (WITHIN RECORD) - while the outer query allows grouping and aggregating over the whole table.

Comment: Thanks @sco, this works great for all the channels except for (Other). 
In Google Analytics I get 14 sessions while in BigQuery I get 1 only. What do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was data related issue, so using lower for comparison solved the issue thus as below so thank you guys.

```
SELECT
  channelGrouping,
  COUNT(1) AS Sessions,
  SUM(nvl(isRafinhaSession,1)) as RafinhaSession
FROM (
  SELECT
    channelGrouping,
    some(LOWER(hits.page.pageTitle) CONTAINS LOWER(('rafinha - Dugout')) ) WITHIN RECORD     isRafinhaSession
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([133338516.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP('2017-10-01'), TIMESTAMP('2017-10-20')))
  WHERE
    totals.visits=1)
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  Sessions DESC
```